Google ads asset names within google ads transfer bigquery data
I need to create a report on asset performance from google ads transfer data in bigquery. The report should be similar to the one in Google Ads UI (under Assets with assets names, campaigns, clicks etc). I have enabled PMAX within the bigquery data transfer and now have views about Assets (e.g. ads_Assets, ads_CampaignAssetStats etc)
When I query ads_CampaignAssetStats I see an asset field campaign_asset_asset of format customers/1111111111/assets/111111111111, I would like to somehow get the name of this particular asset, but I cannot find this in any asset related tables.
So either that data is not available in BQ data transfer and I need to get it from the api or I am not searching or understanding the data. Where can I find this data within BQ data transfer tables (if at all?
I have looked through google ads data transfer documentation expecting some more insights into the asset views but it didn't clarify how I can get the names of the assets.
I have browsed through other tables within BQ google ads data transfer but haven't found a way to connect the data.
